# spring service to check otp code with redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am implementing the following logic to change the password via email using a otp code. the logic is as follows:
the user enters email, the service checks that the user exists, checks if there is a response code for the user with this email, if there is, it returns an error repeat later, if not, it creates a code and saves it in redis with a key as email and a value as code, as well as validity time of 15 minutes.
then the user receives a recovery code on email (implementation will be later in another service for sending mail) he sends this code.

then problems start: I thought I could use the code to find the value of email and find the user to change the password using it. but redis doesn't allow you to do a value lookup to extract the key value from there.
Is there a more elegant solution considering that I need the code to have an expiration date after which it is automatically removed from redis?

going through all the values in a loop doesn't seem like a good idea to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.